# Why does return debugger fail in javascript?

Tags: javascript, specifications

I was doing some refactoring and wanted to break into the debugger and return before getting to a piece of code that made permanent changes so I put in one of my functions

`return debugger;`

And I got an unexpected token error (in chrome).

```
debugger;
return;
```

works just fine. Is there something in the ECMAScript spec that actually specifies this as correct behavior? Is this a browser bug? Is there any particular logic to this failing at all?

Comment: I'm not an expert on this javascript debugger... but why would you want to return it? are you expecting the debugger object in your code? It was my understanding that it's just a directive that triggers the debugger...

Comment: The two are completely different pieces of code. What makes you think that one should work just because the other does? Would you expect `return return;` to be valid, also?

Comment: Also, what would `return debugger;` really _mean_? Where would be the logic in it _not_ failing?

Comment: @jondavidjohn Although the TJ provided the answer below, in answer to your question I was not expecting `return debugger;` to return a debugger object. A not terribly uncommon thing to do is to `return (expression)` even when the expression always returns `undefined` so for example `return MyNotificationSystemOfChoice.notify("Your validation failed");` will simply notify the user AND return immediately. It's just a syntax shortcut but as TJ points out there's a distinction between expressions and statements.

Comment: It's a syntax shortcut that leads to confusing code...  just because it's not uncommon doesn't mean it's good.  I'm with @LightnessRacesinOrbit on this one.

Comment: That's a _terrible_ way to write code.

Comment: It is certainly not bad code if you understand javascript. Look at the jquery codebase. Look at the jslint rules. Look at what coffeescript does. It is a terminating statement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`return`](http://es5.github.com/#x12.9) is optionally followed by an [*Expression*](http://es5.github.com/#x11), which when evaluated becomes the result to return. [`debugger`](http://es5.github.com/#x12.15) is not an expression, it's a [*Statement*](http://es5.github.com/#x12-toc). So `return debugger;` fails for the same reason `return for (i = 0; i < 10; ++i);`, `return if (a > b);`, etc. fail — because you can't use statements as expressions.

Comment: Ah, I see, so `var f = function(){return if(1===1){} }` has the same error. That makes some level of sense.

Comment: I wonder if the debugger statement on the last line of a function would break in coffeescript..

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: `var f = function(){return if(1===1){} }` _does_ have the same error, because of the `if` under the `return`. I don't know why he brought the surrounding function variable definition into it, though. As you can see, it's merely confused matters for everyone.

Comment: @GeorgeMauer: Re CoffeeScript: I would expect it to, for the same reason I would expect it not to ignore any other statement at the end of a function. Doing so would be a bug in CoffeeScript's CoffeeScript->JavaScript translator.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: Doh! Thank you, I totally missed that bit in the middle. :-)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: Mentally applying levels of callstack abstraction as you read code is something to be proud of :)

Comment: @GeorgeMauer: Right, because `return if (1===1)` tries to use a statement where an expression is expected. (In that *particular* case, of course, you could just drop the `if` to get a valid production.)

Answer (score 1):

This is indeed the correct behavior. The reason is that **debugger** is defined to be a *statement*, not an *expression*. This means that it can only be used in a statement context - that is, in the form:

```
debugger;
```

You cannot, however, put it in an expression context, as in

```
return debugger;
```

It's actually the same reason why you cannot write, say,

```
return break;
```

Comment: It is a duplicate; unfortunately, you already posted you answer when I hit the submit button and I failed to see the notification. Sorry.